# Is it properly applied the Quine McCluskey algorithm by this?

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

I'm writing some code for implementing the **Quine McCluskey** algorithm and I simply need to clear out if my logic for implementation is ok.

I get some number of **minterms** and combine each of them so they produce an **implicant**, later I combine these implicants and consider them as **prime implicants**. 
So for the new prime implicants plus the *unchecked* implicants, I treat them as *candidates* for essential implicants.

So I'm talking about two loops here, for the total minterms  right later for total implicants obtained before.

I've tested my code for a few examples and got good results so far but I need to know this works for ***n*** minterms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an optimal solution you need more than "two loops". The selection of a minimum number of implicants is a [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_covering) and was shown to be [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). Selecting a cover with a greedy algorithm just grabs the most promising implicants and is not guaranteed to arrive at an optimal solution.

A good overview on two-level logic minimization was published by [Olivier Coudert](http://www.ocoudert.com/papers/pdf/int94.pdf). Chapter 3 describes the Quine-McCluskey algorithm. This algorithm is of interest for historical reasons but hardly used in practice any more.

For practical experiments, you could try tools like [Logic Friday 1](http://sontrak.com/). It uses the two-level minimizer [Espresso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer). Logic Friday features an exact/fast switch. It allows you to play with the trade-off between solution speed and optimality.

Another tool for experiments is [Karma 3](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/logics/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=52&Itemid=51).